# jQuery Scroll function for a web page is not working out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to set scroll for a web page but it's not working out properly.

What I want is that when someone scroll to the middle of the or at least a little up before the footer element so I want to trigger scroll event and then wait for like 10 to 15 seconds as on triggering the scroll event the data is loaded through ajax which takes time and then each time to do so when someone goes down again to the footer so again the scroll function should get triggered.

What I am working now with is as follows but I want to enhance it to the above requirements :

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('footer').position().top){
        $('div#load_more').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you running a `.click()` in your if statement instead of calling the ajax directly? Also, just calling `.click()` won't trigger a click event in javascript. You would need to do `.trigger('click');` for that

Comment: I can't directly as the ajax is called through somewhere else on click so that's why. Besides yes I changed it to `.trigger('click')` I thought if both of these are working the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window)` instead of `$(document)`

```js
// helper function does exactly what it says
function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
var $canfetch = true;
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
 var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
 var scrollPosition = $(".highlight")[0].offsetTop;
        // if user has reached bottom of page the sleep function for next scroll event will be fired.
 if (scrollPosition-scrollHeight <= 0) {
      if($canfetch)  {
      console.log("ajax call here");
      }
      $canfetch = false;
        // sleep function usage          
      sleep(15000).then(() => {     
      alert("15 seconds have passed");
      // return to top of page
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
      $canfetch = true;
    });
 }
});
```

```css
.ok {
height:500px;
}
.highlight{
height:20px;
text-align:center;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok"></div>
<div class="highlight">Reference Point</div>
<div class="ok"></div>
```

Comment: What I want is to have delays of 15 seconds between next scroll event triggering.

Comment: Can you embed footer or any element into it please i.e so that when someone scrolls to the element i.e just right when the element show up even a little so the scroll should be triggered rather than that it's perfectly right?

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai please check the edited answer the `sleep` function is triggered when user reaches the bottom of the page.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai you mean instead of reaching the bottom of the page to stop until it reaches a certain element?

Comment: Yup exactly I have <footer> also if extra code is also added when a user is near to the bottom in term of pixels.

Comment: Also how would it be possible to only not trigger with sleep on first scroll event but rather on every other event which is not the first i.e not for first time but for every next event.

Comment: Here it is : http://test.canvas-events.co.uk/main_cxqa.php/search/results  Where I am applying it but it's triggering again and again. At first 30 records are loaded and then after that on scrolling to the end of the records next 30 should be loaded.

Comment: Please click on search button if you are redirected to home page to go to the relevant page.

Comment: From what I can see the scroll is triggered once and then again two times as like it is with 3 seconds delay which loads upto 90 records in total which is not correct.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai basically the above snippet will detect the position of the element and sleep for 3 seconds after that. You can't force stop scrolling though. Might i ask do you have a lazy load script running when reach the bottom of the page to fetch more elements using ajax? If yes make a function of your ajax call and use it when `sleep` is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a jsfiddle test of your code and had following observations:
a. Assuming the footer is in a div

- if you are using class='footer' then you have to use
  $('.footer').position().top
- If you are using id='footer' then you have to use   $('#footer').position().top

b. I added console.log($(this).scrollTop() + '~~footer positon top is '+ $('.footer').position().top); and found that the condition is never met.
1671~~footer positon top is 1868 when I scrolled all the way  down.

Hope this helps a bit.

**Side Note**: You might want to consider a cool plugin called ajax load more to achieve similar feature.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below function use $(window) instead of $(document):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    alert("Scrolled");
});
```

Comment: What's the catch here?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!